# how to replace settings item with imagebutton

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am developing a navigation drawer activity in android studio, in menu folder there is a settings item at the left corner. I want to remove it and add an image button over there in action bar. Can anyone tell me how to add that image button and how to perform click event on that button in main activity.

Check below image for reference -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps, add this inside your `menu.xml` layout -

> The showAsAction attribute allows you to define how the action is displayed. For example, the ifRoom attribute defines that the action is only displayed in the action bar if there is sufficient screen space available.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="Settings">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

just try this.
no need to add imagebutton you just need to add

```
 android:showAsAction="always"
```

and icon as

```
 android:icon="@drawable/Your_icon"
```

do this in the menu.xml file, in item setting

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to main_menu.xml in your menu folder under res and modify it as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/image_button"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Clickme"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

In your MainActivity

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
      if(item.getItemId == R.id.image_button){
        //do action on imagebutton click
        return true;
       }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```